# Use object destructuring.eslint(prefer-destructuring)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code. The code is complaining about `Use object destructuring.eslint(prefer-destructuring)` as shown in image in red marks. How i can solve this issue ? I had a look here but https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring not sure where i am doing wrong ?

```
GET_GEOCODE_FROM_ZIPCODE(state, action) {
    const { res } = action;
    if (res && res.address && res.zipcode) {
        const zipcode = res.zipcode;
        const address = res.address;
        return {
            ...state,
            geoCode: {...action.res, address},
            zipcode,
            showCallout: true
        }
    } 
    return state
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also you can just use `geocode: {...res, address}`. You've already destructured `res` on line 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `destructure` your object :

```
const { address, zipcode } = res;
```

Comment: I didnt understood ... why address to zipcode and zipcode to address

Comment: You can read the document as @Tim suggested it, but for simple : you are "extracting" desired attributes of `res` object instead of reassign to a new const.

Answer (score 0):

Eslint wants you to use destructuring:

```
const { zipcode, address } = res;
```

You can read more about object destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):